# Implement rules for realtimeDB when not using auth.uid as user id

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using realtime for my chat and an external database for the rest. I would like to implement the rules for it, but in the docs the only example I found is by comparing the auth.uid to the user_id whic

I have this database structure in real time database:

```js
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "id1": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "id2": { ... },
    "id3": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    "id1": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "id2": { ... },
    "id3": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "id1": {
      "m1": {
        "senderid": "userid2",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "id2": { ... },
    "id3": { ... }
  },
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "name": "test",
      "city": "test",
      "contacts": {
        "userid2": true,
        "userid3": true,
      }
    }
    "userid2": { ... },
    "userid3": { ... }
  }
}
```

this is the example I found but I can't do it because the user_id is not my auth.uid.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$chatId": {
        // Only authenticated users can read chat metadata
        ".read": "auth != null",
        // Only the members of the chat can write to chat metadata
        ".write": "root.child('members/' + $chatId + '/' + auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    },
    "members": {
      "$chatId": {
        // Only authenticated users can read chat members
        ".read": "auth != null",
        // Only the members of the chat can write to chat members
        ".write": "root.child('members/' + $chatId + '/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        // Members can only be added by authenticated users who are already a member of the chat
        "$memberId": {
          ".write": "auth != null && root.child('members/' + $chatId + '/' + auth.uid).exists() && !root.child('members/' + $chatId + '/' + $memberId).exists()"
        }
      }
    },
    "messages": {
      "$chatId": {
        // Only authenticated users can read messages
        ".read": "auth != null",
        // Only members of the chat can write to messages
        ".write": "root.child('members/' + $chatId + '/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        "$messageId": {
          // Only the sender of the message can edit or delete it
          ".write": "root.child('messages/' + $chatId + '/' + $messageId + '/senderid').val() == auth.uid",
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['message', 'timestamp'])"
        }
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        // Only authenticated users can read and write to their own user node
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
        "contacts": {
          // Only authenticated users can read and write to their own contacts
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
          "$contactId": {
            // Only authenticated users can add contacts to their own contacts list
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId && !root.child('users/' + $userId + '/contacts/' + $contactId).exists()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What approach can I take to accomplish this?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rules are just an expression of some requirements you have for data access.  Your question doesn't contain any requirements that you want to implement (except for that fact that you're not using Firebase Auth), so there's not much we can do to help. The only way that Firebase supports per-user security is with Firebase Auth, so you're going to be stuck on that until you do.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't do it because the user_id is not my auth.uid.

If you want to secure access to the data based on the current user, you will have to ensure that information about the current user is available in the security rules of your database.

If you sign in to Firebase with one of the default providers, that information is available in the `auth` variable in your rules automatically. If you use a non-Firebase provider to sign the user in, you can make that information available by [minting a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for that users on a trusted environment, and then [signing in with that customer token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) in the client-side application.